# SwiftUI: How to remove caret right in NavigationLink which is inside a List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a issue about `NavigationLink` in SwiftUI. I have a `List` restaurant and have `NavigationLink` in it. I tried to remove the caret right in right of NavigationLink section but not success

I tried to remove caret using `buttonStyle` but is's not work.

```
List(vm.restaurants) { (restaurant: Restaurant) in
   NavigationLink(destination: ResDetailView(restaurant: restaurant)) {
        RestaurantRow(life: life)
   }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
}
```

[image]

Comment: No way for List (for now). You can use ScrollView instead, within which NavigationLink does not have "caret".

Comment: @Asperi this is not true...there are ways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            List(menu, id: \.self) { section in

                VStack{
                    Text(section.name)
                    NavigationLink(destination: Dest()) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Incredible. My hat's off!

Answer (score 7):

Chris' answer works, but `EmptyView` has a height which adds empty space to the bottom of the cell. Instead, you can use `ZStack` to make the navigation link on top of the cell.

```swift
List {
  ForEach(0..<items.count) { i in
    ZStack {
      ContactRow(item: self.items[i])
      NavigationLink(destination: ChatView()) {
        EmptyView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get rid of the disclosure indicator is to set the padding on the NaviagtionLink:

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: Destination(item: item)) {
                CustomCell(item: item)
            }    .padding([.trailing], -30.0)
        }
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend it though - it's a way of showing your users that there is more data available if the tap on one of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Marin's answer works, but for my use case I conditionally display the cells in a VStack instead of a List using ViewThatFits (to achieve a sticky footer), and in this case SwiftUI just ignores the NavigationLink with an EmptyView.

You can add a Rectangle() in a ZStack, but then the rectangle tries to grow too big and it's annoying to manage keeping it the same size as the underlying view. So, overlay() works great for this. Here's what I ended up with:

```
cellContents
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(16)
            .overlay {
                NavigationLink(value: viewModel.chat) {
                    Rectangle().opacity(0)
                }
            }
```